# Connect to Aws RDS in private subnet via toad

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, toad

I am running an oracle RDS instance inside a private subnet. Now my developers needs to connect to that db via toad for improvements every now and then. How can I let them connect to private oracle RDS via toad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a Bastion Host or "jump box" in the public subnet in your VPC (with a public IP) and then establish a SSH tunnel to port forward to the RDS instance via the Bastion Host.

The Bastion Host can be any linux instance, a t3.nano would be sufficient unless you are transferring large amounts of data.

Once the Linux instance is established and you can login to it, in Putty or Mobaxterm create a tunnel from the developers PC to the RDS endpoint via the Bastion.

In Mobaxterm it will look like this (Tools -> MobaSSHTunnel port forwarding):

[image: Mobaxterm tunnel definition]

This example forwards localhost port 1523 to port 1521 on the RDS instance.

You may need to add or update the security group on your RDS instance to allow inbound access from the bastion host.

In TOAD the developer will connect to localhost and the port being forwarded.

[image: TOAD Connection]

For cost savings and added security the bastion host can be shutdown or even terminated when not required.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed reply man. This MobaSSHTunnel port forwarding via Bastian host is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to bastion host. You can attach Virtual Private Gateway to your VPC, set up a VPN connection between your private subnet (where your RDS sits) and your on-premise gateway/router and connect via SSH using private IP addresses, without the need of bastion host.